# Extracting secondary strucutre data from Swissprot Features tuple Python

Tags: python, tuples, bioinformatics, biopython

I need to be able to determine from a Swissprot file the secondary structure (e.g. strand, helix etc) and domain (eg. signal) of a particular position in a protein. Having looked at the FT line in the swissprot file the results are as follows:

```
RecName: Full=Insulin; Contains: RecName: Full=Insulin B chain; Contains: RecName: Full=Insulin A     chain; Flags: Precursor;
('SIGNAL', 1, 24, '{ECO:0000269|PubMed:14426955}.', '')
('PEPTIDE', 25, 54, 'Insulin B chain.', 'PRO_0000015819')
('PROPEP', 57, 87, 'C peptide.', 'PRO_0000015820')
('PEPTIDE', 90, 110, 'Insulin A chain.', 'PRO_0000015821')
('STRAND', 26, 29, '{ECO:0000244|PDB:4EFX}.', '')
('HELIX', 33, 43, '{ECO:0000244|PDB:3W7Y}.', '')
('HELIX', 44, 46, '{ECO:0000244|PDB:3W7Y}.', '')
('HELIX', 91, 97, '{ECO:0000244|PDB:3W7Y}.', '')
('STRAND', 98, 101, '{ECO:0000244|PDB:4EFX}.', '')
('HELIX', 102, 106, '{ECO:0000244|PDB:3W7Y}.', '')
('TURN', 107, 109, '{ECO:0000244|PDB:1HIQ}.', '')
```

This format has thrown me, I am guessing it is nested tuples. If given a position for an amino acid eg. 45 how can I extract the information to determine that is is in a helix?

My code so far is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import sys 
import os
from Bio import ExPASy 
from Bio import SwissProt 

# This section receives the parameters from user input via the website:
# This will be commented out during the development period and temp. 
# variables will be used.

# acc_number = sys.argv[1]
# wild_aa = sys.argv[2]
# position = sys.arg[3]
# mutant_aa = sys.arg[4]

#Temp variables for developing:

acc_number = 'P01308'
wild_aa = 'L'
position = '43'
mutant_aa = 'P'

handle = ExPASy.get_sprot_raw(acc_number)

# this reads the swissprot file:
record = SwissProt.read(handle)

# test to see if record has been retrieved:
print record.description

# next section will parse the sequence information using the position variable
# and then will determine the secondary structure and domain location of the mutation

# accessing the secondary structure and domain information from FT lines
for feature in record.features:
   print feature
```

I am reading up like crazy on tuples (been tryign for nearly a week now) and think I have worked out how to extract information from them, it is more of a case once done matching the position to the secondary structure.

I hope I have made sense,
Ally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the items within your tuples by their index, so the feature start would be feature[1] and the end would be feature[2]. To print only features that overlap your position of interest, you can use something like:

```
if feature[1] <= position and feature[2] >= position:
    print feature
```

(Note that this will only work if position is numeric. In your code, it's a string. You need to remove the quotes around the value.)

Comment: Okay, I have finished banging my head against my desk, deleted the overly long version I was crawling towards and gone for this short elegant solution. It works, THANK YOU